# How to disable Request Management on a single WFE vs all WFEs

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, request-management

10 server farm with 5 WFEs with F5 load balancer.

We want to disable RM on a single WFE to make it a dedicated crawl target. I have found how to disable RM across the whole farm, and how to disable the server from the RM pool, but that seems to only stop other servers from sending requests to that server, not stopping that server from sending out requests to the other WFEs.

So how do you disable RM on a single server so all traffic to that WFE stays on it?

Comment: whats the role of your WFE servers? WFE minrole or custom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried this powershell, it will disable / unprovision RM service on the server:

```
$Ser = get-spserviceinstance -Server "your server name"| ? {$_.TypeName -eq "Request Management"}
$ser | Stop-SPServiceInstance
```

You just need to put your server name their and run it.wait for couple of minute and get the status of the RM (you will see it is online on all except the one you disable).

```
get-spserviceinstance | ? {$_.TypeName -eq "Request Management"}
```

Note: this will only work if you have custom minrole, if not then nightly rule will enable it again.

[Description of MinRole and associated services in SharePoint Servers 2016](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/description-of-minrole-and-associated-services-in-sharepoint-server-2016)

Comment: Will it be reprovisioned every night since its not disabled in CA?

Comment: Whats minrole you have on that server? if you have custom then it will not.

Comment: The minrole is Front-End. So we would have to change the minrole to custom to keep the RM from reprovisioning?

Comment: that is correct, If not then a health rule every night will fix the server as per Minrole  and start the instance which should be running.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Does changing the minrole of a server in CA cause any outage on any other server in the farm? Or will it only affect the server you are changing the minrole of?

Comment: it will cause the outage on the server for sure but if you are running any services on that server then it will impact it as well